# Duplicates when trying to modify a DataTable List

Tags: c#, list, datatable

I'm currently working with a DataTable List. I want to get the last item from the list, modify it, and add it to the list as a new item. When I get all values from `tblSol`, all items in the list have the same value. Where did I go wrong?

```
List<DataTable> tblsol = new List<DataTable>();
    int itr = 1;

//some code to iterate these 3 lines below
DataTable now = tblsol.Last();
//some code here to modify now
addToList(now);

private void addToList(DataTable dt)
    {
        DataTable temp = new DataTable();
        temp = dt;
        tblsol.Add(temp);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Iterasi" + itr);
        itr++;
    }
```

Comment: You should take a look at value and reference types in .NET

Answer (score 0):

If you assign a `DataTable` to another `DataTable` both will be same if you require to have same `DataTable` you can use `Copy` method of `DataTable` and than add in `list`.

```
DataTable temp = new DataTable();
temp = dt.Copy();
tblsol.Add(temp);
```